# Difference between calling async EventHandler

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, .net-core, eventhandler

I have an EventHandler defined like this:

```
EventHandler<DataValueChangedEventArgs> method;
```

What is the difference between calling the method, between the following lines 1 and 2:

```
 1. await Task.Run(() => { method.Invoke(this, valueEvent); }); 
 2. method.BeginInvoke(this, valueEvent, EndAsyncEvent, null);
```

The second line doesn't work on .NET Core (NotSupported exception), how can I migrate line 2 to .NET Core equivalent?

Comment: Check out this blog post that talks about removal of Begin/EndInvoke for delegates https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/migrating-delegate-begininvoke-calls-for-net-core/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how can I migrate line 2 to .NET Core equivalent?

`BeginInvoke` invokes the delegate on a thread pool thread. So does `Task.Run`.

So the modern equivalent is the line 1 you already posted.